# How to pass an object reference in HTML through a angular component property?

Tags: html, angular

```
<app-user-profile-photo username = "{{ username }}"
 designation = "{{ designation }}"
 userId = "{{ userId }}"></app-user-profile-photo>
```

This is the above html which is enclosed inside another component.

In the typescript of the the enclosing element, I have defined these variables which are passed dynamically using string interpolation. But this looks ugly as there are so many properties. I want to pass an object which has all these variables. I know I can pass an object when using ngFor, as we have a local reference there. But how do I pass a single object which is present in .ts file dynamically? I have tried every other permutation combination of the syntax. But doesn't seem to work. I feel there is a simple work around. I am new to JS and Angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use the binding syntax without the string interpolation

eg

```
<app-user-profile-photo [username] = "username"
[designation] = "designation"
[userId] = "userId"></app-user-profile-photo>
```

[object] for one way binding or
[(object)] for two way binding

Comment: Lets say I have an object named "user" and a property name userprofile. <app-user-profile-photo 
[(userprofile)] = "user"
></app-user-profile-photo>. Is this correct?

Comment: yes, have a look at the angular heros tutorial https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt1 specifically the two way binding section